# UWP problems in detecting the "Enter" key pressed

Tags: c#, uwp, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to run some functions in my app when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed on the keyboard, but I'm having problems in doing that.

`KeyboardControl` is in the `KeyDown` of my textbox.

`Key.Enter` is not recognized as a function, and I don't know what to do.

```
    // When a key is pressed on the keyboard
    private void KeyboardControl(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyStatus == Key.Enter)
        {
            PercentCalc();

            PercentageValue.Text = Convert.ToString(result, new CultureInfo("en-US")) + "%";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you try to say with "_I'm having problems in doing that_" and "_Key.Enter is not recognized as a function_". Do you get a compile error? Or does your program not behave as you expect? In the latter case, first use the debugger (breakpoint) to check whether your _KeyboardControl_ event handler is actually being called. If it is, use the step-into/single-step features of the debugger to verify whether the PercentCalc actually does what you think it should do. Then, if you have a better picture of the problem, edit and improve your question here with more detail.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to replicate, poorly, what the [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) is meant to be used for. At any rate, this question is most probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You should ask about the issue you are *really* trying to solve, instead of asking about your proposed solution. From the sounds of it, this isn't a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach **KeyDown** event to your **TexBox** like this :

```
<TextBox KeyDown="Box_KeyDown" />
```

at the backend keydown event check if the pressed key is **Enter** and then execute your code in that if condition.

```
private async void Box_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {//execute code here
        PercentCalc();

        PercentageValue.Text = Convert.ToString(result, new CultureInfo("en-US")) + "%";

    }
}
```

> you were trying to check the **KeyStatus** which is not required in your usecase, instead you should be checking which key is pressed.

Comment: That is assuming, that the TextBox has input focus, and that a TextBox even exists. None of that seems to be, what the OP is asking for.

Comment: please read the question again it is clearly stated that "keydown" event of textbox is being used in the code, but the problem was in usage of the comparison (e.KeyStatus == Key.Enter) which was incorrect, so I clarified that with complete code which is easy to understand even for beginners.

Comment: Still the wrong solution. I understand, that the [tag:c#] tag is pretty much a lost cause. It would still be favorable to see contributors try to maintain a certain level of quality. Dealing with raw input messages is, in the vast majority of cases, the wrong solution to any problem. Instead, respond to higher-level abstractions.

Comment: feel free to add a better solution as an answer so I can learn more about how to give better solutions, Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much!